# Difference in height of DIVs

Tags: html, css

I have a main division in which two divisions are present

One is left DIV and another is right DIV

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ys4jv/)

HTML is

```
<div class="main">

    <div class="left">
        Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. 
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        some text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text here
    </div
    </div>
```

And CSS is

```
body
{
 background-color:black;   
}
.main
{
    width:80%;
    background-color:White;
    opacity:0.9;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:25px;
}
.left
{
    width:68%;
    float:left;
    background-color:White;
    padding:2%;
    font-family:Calibri;
}

.right
{
    background-color:White;
    width:26%;
    padding:1%;
    float:right;
}
```

I want both the DIVs must be of equal height always.No matter how much text is present in it.

Now Height of my right DIV is less than left DIV as in fiddle.

Help Me. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Add this to .main height: 30%; overflow: auto; Link: http://jsfiddle.net/Ys4jv/6/

Comment: @AllanKimmerJensen you can see the fiddle and also code present in question it is not readymade code.

Comment: @broadband thnx it works. awesome!!

Comment: @broadband post it as answer

Comment: @broadband ok i am posting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to .main

```
height: 30%;
overflow: auto;
```

Link: [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ys4jv/6/)

Comment: Just to limit height. Let's say height is 200px. When either div (left or right) content is larger that 200px, then vertical scrollbar appears. Nothing else.